# How to run shell commands and capture there output into a UML diagram

Tags: plantuml

I have a footer that generates info about the diagram, like the date and user who created the image. I would like to include the git SHA. I need some sort of built-in function, probably a preprocessor function, that lets me envoke system commands. I'm thinking something like the %date() command, only where I pass in the command and arguments I want to be executed and I get back the text from it being run in the shell. Something like

%sys_call("git rev-parse --short=10 HEAD")

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you could achieve this but it would require a bit of scripting:

**Solution 1/:**
Pass the git sha through an environment variable and use
`%getenv` function to retrieve it from the plantuml file
see here: https://plantuml.com/en/preprocessing#291cabbe982ff775

**Solution 2/:**
Have a script that write the sha in a text file and include this file from your plantuml file:
https://plantuml.com/en/preprocessing#393335a6fd28a804